# Label for Child in Simple Hierarchical Select by using a module

Tags: webforms

While using Simple Hierarchical Select Module, I have 2 levels of Hierarchy for my Phone. Is it possible to label for child by using a module ?

[image: While using Simple Hierarchical Select Module, I have 2 levels of Hierarchy for my Phone.]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess this is possible by Client side hierarchical select.

Let me know if there is any other option.

Thanks.